# Elastic Beanstalk and Spring Boot Redirect HTTP to HTTPS

Tags: spring-boot, https, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a spring boot app where the compiled JAR is deployed to elastic beanstalk.

I have one load balancer instance. On this instance, I have a listener on port 443 serving HTTPS to EC2 instance on port 80. (HTTPS terminated at load balancer).

In EB, i configured the same load balancer listener. When I make requests to the server using HTTPS everything is all good.

I am wondering how to keep this functionality while making sure that any HTTP requests forward to HTTPS so the load balancer instance can handle it using HTTPS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elastic Beanstalk uses nginx as the reverse proxy to map your application to your Elastic Load Balancing load balancer on port 80. Elastic Beanstalk provides a default nginx configuration that you can either extend or override completely with your own configuration.

To extend Elastic Beanstalk's default nginx configuration, add .conf configuration files to a folder named .ebextensions/nginx/conf.d/ in your application source bundle. Elastic Beanstalk's nginx configuration includes .conf files in this folder automatically.

Refer [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/java-se-nginx.html)

Add the below block to  *.ebextensions/nginx/nginx.conf*  and redeploy

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;

    server_name _;

    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```